# Server or HTML isn't displaying CSS (but works when opening HTML file)

Tags: html, css, node.js

I've been trying to learn how to set up a node.js server for a simple website for the first time and am encountering some strange behavior. When I open my index.html file from my computer it opens up perfectly with all of the CSS working properly. However I then set up a basic node.js server and when accessing the index.html file through my browser it only loads the html but not the CSS.

I'm extremely new to this so haven't been able to try much, also because the code is extremely simple so can't see what's missing (I tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBOUfdUZIVo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp&index=17) tutorial if that helps). I also found another question that seemed similar on here but it didn't have an answer and didn't really help, I did check that all the files are UTF-8.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>A headline</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And the node.js server:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  const myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/index.html", "utf8");
  myReadStream.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log("Listening to port 3000");
```

When I include the CSS within `<style>` tags and directly in index.html it does work, but I've tried putting `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">` between `<style>` tags and that still doesn't (it would also be weird if that's necessary seeing as it displays perfectly when I simply open the html file). I've also tried removing `type=text/css` but that didn't seem to change anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not a node expert, but it looks like you're only serving the `index.html` and nothing else. Your server has no idea what `styles.css`, so when your page loads, it's trying to request `styles.css` from the server, but it can't process that request. I might be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve the `style.css` as well. You are serving the `index.html` but in the index.html it is hitting `http://127.0.0.1:300/style.css` when the request is coming to your app it is STILL serving the `index.html` file. (You can confirm this in Network pane of developer tools)

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  const url = req.url;
  if (url === '/style.css') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' }); // http header
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/style.css", "utf8").pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); // http header
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/index.html", "utf8").pipe(res);
  }
})
```

**Note:** It is very easy to achieve this using [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), probably the most popular nodejs package.

Comment: Just had a thought - would I have to do this to load images as well? As those don't seem to be showing up either

Comment: Yes every route that is being hit, you need to handle Everything. But you can use a package called `http-server` to run an http server if you just want to serve.